# How do I get the Threads window in VisualStudio2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multithreading

How do you get this window in VisualStudio 2008:

[alt text http://sarathc.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/image-thumb6.png](http://sarathc.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/image-thumb6.png)

I am especially looking at the "View" menu.  It's just not there.  I have a non-Express version of VisualStudio 2008.  I found the above screenshot via google..that's the window I need.  Any way to make that window open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While debugging, try:

Debug > Windows > Threads

Or Control+D, T (on my machine at least)

Answer (score 2):

Debug -> Windows -> Threads

All Debugger windows and functions are hidden under the Debug menu. This is probably to reduce confusion, but clearly had the opposite affect for you.

Comment: Mine is a copy of Jay's. His answer had not appeared while I was typing mine. Vote for his.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be executing the application, then open the Debug menu, select Windows then Threads.